Error: With Swift ViewModifier using NavigationLink: Generic parameter could not be inferred
I'm encountering an issue with a custom Swift ViewModifier that utilizes a NavigationLink. The ViewModifier, named LinkTo, aims to conditionally present a view using NavigationLink based on a binding boolean value. However, I'm encountering several errors that are hindering the implementation.
The main problem lies in the body function of the LinkTo ViewModifier. The body function attempts to use the navigationDestination modifier, which is not a valid modifier. This results in the error "Generic parameter 'V' could not be inferred". Additionally, when trying to pass the destination closure as the destination argument of the navigationDestination, another error occurs: "Cannot convert value of type 'V0' to expected argument type '()->'". Lastly, there's an issue with a trailing closure that's being passed, causing the error "Extra trailing closure passed in call".
Despite attempting various adjustments, I'm unable to resolve these errors. Any insights or guidance on how to correct these issues would be highly appreciated. Thank you!
struct LinkTo<V0: View>: ViewModifier {
@Binding var isActive: Bool
let destination: () -> V0

init(@ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> V0, isActive: Binding<Bool>) {
    self.destination = content
    self._isActive = isActive
}

func body(content: Content) -> some View {
    content
        .background(
            NavigationLink(
                destination: destination(),
                isActive: $isActive
            ) {
                EmptyView()
            }
            .isDetailLink(false)
        )
}}

I attempted to create a custom Swift ViewModifier named LinkTo to conditionally present a view using NavigationLink based on a binding boolean value. I expected the ViewModifier to compile successfully and function as intended, allowing me to use it in my SwiftUI views to trigger navigation based on a boolean state. However, when compiling the code, I encountered errors related to generic parameter inference, conversion of types, and trailing closure issues. These errors prevented the successful compilation of the code, resulting in failure to implement the intended functionality of the ViewModifier.
struct LinkTo<V0: View>: ViewModifier {

@Binding var isActive: Bool
let destination: () -> V0

init(@ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> V0, isActive: Binding<Bool>) {
    self.destination = content
    self._isActive = isActive
}

func body(content: Content) -> some View {
    content
        .navigationDestination( // Generic parameter 'V' could not be inferred
            isPresented: $isActive, // Cannot convert value of type 'V0' to expected argument type '()->'
            destination: destination()
        ) { // Extra trailing closure passed in call
            EmptyView()
        }
        .disabled(true)
        .hidden()
}}


What iOS versions are you supporting? This way of programmatic navigation is deprecated in iOS 16.

I'm trying to IOS version 17.0

Then you don't need this view modifier. It is already built-in as navigationDestination(isPresented:destination:).
